# I need help writing a sql query to concat multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have table with following information

```
id | order_id | batch_id | bucket_id | menu_id | product_id | type_id | size
1  | 1        | 1        | 1         | 1       | 1          | 1       | small
2  | 1        | 1        | 1         | 1       | 5          | 1       | small
3  | 1        | 1        | 1         | 1       | 5          | 1       | medium
```

I want to achieve following

```
order_id | batch_id | product1 | product5
1        | 1        | 1 x small| 1 x small, 1 medium
```

Is this possible to write a query to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know how many different products there would be?  If not, you would probably need to write a stored procedure to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible in MySQL using this *kind* of query:

```
SELECT order_id, batch_id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN product_id=1 THEN CONCAT(type_id,' x ', size) END) AS product1, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN product_id=5 THEN CONCAT(type_id,' x ', size) END) AS product5
FROM table1
GROUP BY order_id, batch_id
```

The problem with this is that it's not dynamic so if you have hundreds, thousands of products, the query will be very hard to maintain. One possible solution in MySQL is using prepared statement. Here is an **updated** example after @ggordon spotted that my previous attempt show duplicates:

```
SET @columns := (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT("GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN product_id=",product_id," 
                     THEN CONCAT(cnt,' x ', size) END)  
                      AS product",product_id,"
                    ")) 
               FROM (SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM table1) t1);
SET @query := CONCAT('SELECT order_id, batch_id, ',@columns,' 
                    FROM (SELECT product_id, order_id, batch_id, size, COUNT(*) cnt 
                            FROM table1 GROUP BY product_id, order_id, batch_id, size) t1 
                    GROUP BY order_id, batch_id');
PREPARE stmt FROM @query ;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

There are 2 variables being used in there and I named each variable to represent what is it (hopefully).

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b851af94811a342cbf69356d383f4f2c)

Comment: You may want to re-visit your dynamic query and test this approach again. I've added additional sample data to your fiddle to show duplicate output [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77bb3768f27c9bce5ea41b509faaa7f9)

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I'll update accordingly, thanks for spotting it!

Answer (score 0):

The following query would return the desired data you would need

```
SELECT
    order_id,
    batch_id,
    product_id,
    concat(
        count(product_id),
        ' x ',
        size
    ) as size_cnt
FROM
    t1
GROUP BY
    order_id,
    batch_id,
    product_id,
    size;
```

| order_id | batch_id | product_id | size_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 x small |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 x small |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 1 x medium |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wTrhCYZyqpXsPXGYrLZBvP/1)

However, in order to get it in the desired format, you would need to pivot the data. You could achieve this with the assistance of `group_concat` as shown in the sql example below:

```sql
SELECT
    order_id,
    batch_id,
    -- we can generate from here
    REPLACE(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            ',',
            CASE
                WHEN product_id=1 THEN size_cnt
            END
        ),
        ',,',
        ','
    ) as product1,
    REPLACE(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            ',',
            CASE
                WHEN product_id=5 THEN size_cnt
            END
        ),
        ',,',
        ','
    ) as product5
    -- to here. See explanation below
FROM (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        batch_id,
        product_id,
        concat(
            count(product_id),
            ' x ',
            size
        ) as size_cnt
    FROM
        t1
    GROUP BY
        order_id,
        batch_id,
        product_id,
        size
) t2
GROUP BY
   order_id,
   batch_id
```

| order_id | batch_id | product1 | product5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ,1 x small | ,1 x small,1 x medium |

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wTrhCYZyqpXsPXGYrLZBvP/1)

However, as you can see, you would have to know the product_ids before hand for the desired columns.

If you are uncertain about the product ids that you will have, writing a dynamic query would be helpful here. You could start by getting all the product_ids.

I'm using the DB facade from Laravel here, however, you may use the Eloquent ORM or other methods to achieve the following:

```php
//I have a collection of product ids i.e. `collect([1,5])` based on your example
$productIds = DB::select("select distinct product_id from t1")
                 ->pluck('product_id');
```

Then generating a dynamic sql query to run on your table

```php
$productExpression = DB::select("select distinct product_id from t1")
                 ->pluck('product_id')
                 //for each product id let us return an sql expression
                 ->map(function($productId){
                     return "
                     REPLACE(
                         GROUP_CONCAT(
                             ',',
                             CASE
                                 WHEN product_id=$productId THEN size_cnt
                             END
                         ),
                         ',,',
                         ','
                     ) as product$productId
                     ";
                 })
                 
                 //combine the expressions into one string
                 ->join(",");
```

We can now create a combined query as

```php
$combinedQuery="
SELECT
    order_id,
    batch_id,
    $productExpression
FROM (
    SELECT
        order_id,
        batch_id,
        product_id,
        concat(
            count(product_id),
            ' x ',
            size
        ) as size_cnt
    FROM
        t1
    GROUP BY
        order_id,
        batch_id,
        product_id,
        size
) t2
GROUP BY
   order_id,
   batch_id;
";

//running the query to retrieve the results
$results = DB::select($combinedQuery);
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Aren't you genius and so helpful. Btw, don't hate me but if I say I am using Laravel would that make any difference to any of this you sent? I tried the non dynamic query and it seems to be working good so far. So I'll work on making it dynamic.

Comment: it works like a dream. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

If you are using php with either PDO or mysqli you can get PHP to concat the fields.

```
   $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE");
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    //do stuff with data
    $product .= $row["product_id"] . " x " . $row["size"].", ";
   }
```